# Find rank 1 and rank 2 of grouped values in DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following python dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"dish"     : ["fish", "chicken", "fish", "chicken", "chicken", "veg","veg"],
...                         "location" : ["central", "central", "north", "north", "south", "central", "north"],
...                         "sales" : [1,3,5,2,4,2,2]})
>>> total_sales = df1.groupby(by="dish").sum().reset_index().set_index(["dish"])
>>> df1["proportion_sales"] = df1.apply((lambda row: row["sales"]/total_sales.loc[row["dish"]]), axis=1)
>>> df1
      dish location  sales  proportion_sales
0     fish  central      1          0.166667
1  chicken  central      3          0.333333
2     fish    north      5          0.833333
3  chicken    north      2          0.222222
4  chicken    south      4          0.444444
5      veg  central      2          0.500000
6      veg    north      2          0.500000
```

I want to find out the ranked 1 and ranked 2 dish for each `location`. For example, in `central`, `chicken` is ranked 1 and `fish` is ranked 3.

How do I update the `dish_rank_in_location` df to be like so? This is what I have:

```
      dish location  sales  proportion_sales  rank
0     fish  central      1          0.166667     1
1  chicken  central      3          0.333333     1
2     fish    north      5          0.833333     1
3  chicken    north      2          0.222222     1
4  chicken    south      4          0.444444     1
5      veg  central      2          0.500000     1
6      veg    north      2          0.500000     1
```

expected output:

```
      dish location  sales  proportion_sales  dish_rank_in_location
0     fish  central      1          0.166667     3
1  chicken  central      3          0.333333     2
2     fish    north      5          0.833333     1
3  chicken    north      2          0.222222     3
4  chicken    south      4          0.444444     1
5      veg  central      2          0.500000     1
6      veg    north      2          0.500000     2
```

Comment: Check your expected output? Everything is rank 1.

Comment: yes the problem is the rank 1 needs to be updated to rank 2, 3. that's the problem of this question

Comment: Ok. What about `df1.groupby(['location']).proportion_sales.rank(method='dense')`?

Comment: Can you please provide some kind of expected output?

Comment: i've updated with the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `rank` with `ascending=False` here.

```
df1['dish_rank_in_location'] = df1.groupby('location')\
               .proportion_sales.rank(method='dense', ascending=False)

df1

      dish location  sales  proportion_sales  dish_rank_in_location
0     fish  central      1          0.166667                    3.0
1  chicken  central      3          0.333333                    2.0
2     fish    north      5          0.833333                    1.0
3  chicken    north      2          0.222222                    3.0
4  chicken    south      4          0.444444                    1.0
5      veg  central      2          0.500000                    1.0
6      veg    north      2          0.500000                    2.0
```

If you need the rank as an integer, you can always make a cast -

```
df1['dish_rank_in_location'].astype(int)

0    3
1    2
2    1
3    3
4    1
5    1
6    2
Name: dish_rank_in_location, dtype: int64
```

Assign the result back.